# Custom Operator XCom during run time in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I understand for `PythonOperator/BashOperator` we can use Xcom to communicate.

e.g.

```
def func(**context):
    context['task_instance'].xcom_pull()
```

However, I am wondering how to access `xcom` for a custom operator during run time.

My operator looks like this:

```
class ECHOXOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = x
        super(ECHOXOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.x)
```

So in my DAG:

I can do

```
task2 = ECHOXOperator(x = 'Hello")
```

And it works well. But how can I access x from an upstream task?

Something like:

```
def task1(**context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="x", value="Hello")

generate_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task1",
    python_callable=task1,
    dag=dag,
)

task2 = ECHOXOperator(x = task_instance.xcom_pull('task1', 'x'), provide_context=True)

task1 >> task2
```

This is not working because `task_instance` in `ECHOXOperator` is not defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass `x` as **templated_fields** in your Custom Operator.

```py
class ECHOXOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ['x']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = x
        super(ECHOXOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.x)
```

And now you can do the following to get the value of Xcom passed in previous task:

```py
def task1(**context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="x", value="Hello")

generate_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task1",
    python_callable=task1,
    dag=dag,
)

task2 = ECHOXOperator(x = "{{ ti.xcom_pull('task1', 'x') }}")

task1 >> task2
```

More information regarding **templated_fields** and Jinja templating: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#id1

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to pass other data types? For example, `list`, `dict`. Should I use `pickle`?

Comment: You can pass other data types as well, they would be rendered recursively. Example you can pass something like `task2 = ECHOXOperator(x = ["{{ ti.xcom_pull('task1', 'x') }}", "hello", "hi"])`

Comment: Read the first line and it worked. I wish i could have landed here on first day.
Many Thanks